# Calculated correctly? Poisson distribution question

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

A break room can hold max 20 people, if any more come by they have to wait outside You decide to count the number of people (they always come alone) passing by, in 10-minute intervals between 11.30 - 12.30. We assume that the number of people heading towards the break room in any 10-minute interval between 11.30 - 12.30 is a random variable, $N$. You repeatedly measure over the course of a few days, and conclude that approximately follows a Poisson distribution with $\lambda = 5$. Assume the break room is empty at 11:30.

a) What is the probability that 4 people, or fewer, enter the break room in the interval 11:30 - 11:40?
Here - I have calculated like this:
$$Px(X)=\frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!}$$
$$Px(4) =\frac{5^4×e^{-5}}{4!}$$

b) Assume then that one day there are 16 people in the break room by 12:10. How probable are you to get company, of someone forced to wait outside, within the coming 20 minutes?
I have done like this:
$$P[X\ge 4] = 1 - P[X \le 4] = 1 - \left[\frac{5^0 × e^{-5}} {0!} +\frac{5^1 × e^{-5}}{1!} +...\right]$$

Have I done this correctly?

Comment: It's hard to read unformatted math.  For the first question, you appear to be computing the probability that *exactly* four people enter in that window, but you were asked for the probability that *at most* four people enter.  For the second, it would appear that we need information about how long people stay in the break room.  If, unphysically, you choose to assume that nobody ever leaves the break room, then keep in mind that you are asked about $20$ minutes, not $10$.

Comment: [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial on formatting.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for your feedback - I'm new with this all

Comment: For the second part it is also unclear if the $N$ for 12:10-12:20 is independent from the $N$ for 12:20-12:30.

Answer (score -1):

The random variable $N$ which follows a Poisson distribution with intensity parameter $5$, measures the number of people heading towards the break room every $10$ minutes interval
However in part b of the question, we are required to find the probability that more than 4 people heads towards the break room in the interval $12:10$ to $12:30$ i.e. a $20$ min interval.

Follow this approach:
Let $N_1, N_2$ be the random variables measuring the no of people heading in the $10$ min intervals: $12:10-12:20$, $12:20-12:30$.
Thus, the total no of people heading towards the room is $N= N_1+N_2$
Now note that, $N_i$'s are iid (independent and identically distributed) random variables. And we have a property of poisson distribution that if $X$ and $Y$ follows $poi(\lambda)$ and $poi(\mu)$ respectively, $X+Y$ follows $poi(\lambda+\mu)$. The proof is quite simple, you can try it on your own.

Thus, $N$ follows $poi(5+5)$ or $poi(10)$.
Now you can use the process you have used, except your intensity parameter would be $10$.

Also in part a we are required to find $4$ or fewer people entering the room, i.e. $P(N≤4)$  but you have calculated $P(N=4)$

Note: The independence of the random variables $N_1$ and $N_2$ is supported by the fact that the number of people heading toward the room in ANY 10 min interval is a $poi(5)$ random variable, which is an approximation made in the given question. In real world however, this independence may not hold true.

Comment: I see, the intensity should be doubled given the time frame. Thank you @user960402

Comment: Why are $N_1$ and $N_2$ independent?

Comment: @ronno $N_1$ and $N_2$ are independent because the number of people heading towards the room in any 10 minute interval has no effect on the people heading towards the room in any other 10 min interval. This is because we are told that the no of people heading towards the room in 10 min interval is a Poisson r.v with parameter lambda, here we don't have to use any information about other r.v.s thus they are independent.

Comment: -1 If you are using real-world intuition to justify the independence then I disagree, people certainly coordinate their break schedules (positively or negatively) for various reasons. If the point is that the question is unanswerable without making this assumption then you should be explicit that this is an assumption and not state it as if it follows from the other givens.

Comment: @ronno You are right, the independence is an assumption made, what I argued was that the information given itself is an approximation that "that the number of people heading towards the break room in any 10-minute interval between 11.30 - 12.30 is a random variable, N" and "and conclude that approximately follows a Poisson distribution with λ=5". Obviously in real world, we don't have this kind of independence, nor any event that exactly follow certain standard distribution. So I said that as per the given information(Which is an approximation) the numbers are independent.